# Как правильно объявлять и реализовывать шаблоны в С++

Tags: c++

Как правильно объявлять и использовать шаблонные классы в этом костыльном языке без нормальных дженериков?
Допустим, я объявил шаблонный класс в файле foo.h и реализовал в foo.cpp, подключил foo.h в главном модуле и получил ошибку сборки. Вспомнить точно, в чем заключалась ошибка, я уже не смогу, а воспроизводить ее и писать код мне лень, но, думаю, все понимают, о чем я говорю.

Если подключить хедер с шаблоном в двух разных местах и использовать с разными типами, то тогда вообще будет ад. Компилятор не сможет слинковать части программы, и будет крыть меня матом.

В качестве решения можно перенести реализацию шаблонного класса в хедер, но тогда теряется смысл заголовочных файлов.

Что-то можно сделать с этими проблемами? Шаблоны - удобная штука, но не в С++.

Comment: Возможно, данный вопрос будет полезен: ["Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: В чём состоит Ваш вопрос?

Comment: Смысла у хедер-файлов и так немного — это наследие того времени, когда памяти было 12 Кб, и разделение кода на сигнатуру и имплементацию компилятор спихивал на программиста. Пишите реализацию шаблонов в хедере.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите код в заголовочных файлах, в этом нет ничего плохого, особенно если Вы начинающий, и в проекте всего несколько десятков файлов.

Потом с опытом придет понимание того, какой код где размещать, где использовать статический, а где динамический полиморфизм.